# Pandas DataFrame substring match not working

Tags: python, string, pandas

My dataframe contains sender name which I only want to display certain senders.
Column name in the dataframe is Senders.

```
1                                         Tin, Heather-LK
2                                         Wong, Wan Sing
3                                     Employee Engagement
4                                           Loh, Kelly-KK
5                           EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP
6                                               CorpComms
7                                            Loo Wai Long
8                                         Tang, Heather-L
9                                                  Oracle
```

Code

```
df[df.Sender.str.contains('Tin', na=False)]
```

Results are a blank dataframe. I do not understand as clearly the string attribute contains the part which I am looking for.

Below are the dataframe's info

```
1378
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1378 entries, 0 to 1377
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Sender           1375 non-null object
Content          1378 non-null object
Received Time    1378 non-null object
Replied Time     189 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 53.8+ KB
```

If I rebuild the frame by my own, it works. But cannot seem to get it to work on the original data that I have extracted through Outlook MAPI.

Comment: May be a type issue, what do you get if you do `df.Sender.map(lambda s: type(s)).head()`?

Comment: `0    <type 'instance'> Name: Sender, dtype: object` You might be right. Have not encountered this before, was always wrapped around _dtype_ only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, so the results of `df.Sender.map(type).head()` suggest that the items in the `Sender` column are not actually strings but instances of some other class (maybe something specific to the Outlook API?). `object` dtype columns can contain objects of any type, so sometimes you run into issues like this and you need to check the types in individual cells to understand what's happening.

You could try explicitly converting these items to string to see if that fixes your issue:

```
df['Sender_str'] = df['Sender'].map(str)
df.loc[df['Sender_str'].str.contains('Tin', na=False), :]
```

Comment: Done. Explicit map solved my issue. The outlook properties accessor gets its values as type 'instance' and therefore 'str.contains' did not work. Great help thanks! End to end solution will be to create a function to map non str columns to strings during extraction. =D

Comment: Crazy. I don't really even know why this worked over df.where() clause, but it did. Seems like odd behavior but thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can just use `.isin()`:

```
find = df[df['Sender'].isin(['Tin'])]
print (find)
```

Comment: `Returned with this error: TypeError: unhashable instance`.  Just confused why contains does not return me with the results.

Comment: @user3288092 Yes, you're right, my bad, I didn't read your post carefully. Your code should actually work provided you assign it to a `variable` then you print that `variable`. `x = df[df.Sender.str.contains('Tin', na=False)]` then print `x`